# help translating complex sentence

Tags: translation

there are some sentences, I can not understand here are:

1) 为什么一有缺憾就拼命去补足？

2) 这个圆满就有了缺憾；但正因缺憾，未来就有了无限的转机，无限的可能性，

these two sentences I dont understand can you translate and explain?

Comment: can you translate the sentences ?

Comment: 1) Why does a(ny) gap have to be filled as soon as it is felt?
2) A gap appearing in a perfect result, but because of it the future holds unlimited possibilities for improvement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1:

为什么 why is it that

一…就 as soon as

有缺憾 there is a shortcoming

拼命 (that one should) go the extreme lengths

去补足 to make up for the deficiency

2:

这个圆满 this satisfactory (result)

就有了缺憾 suffers from shortcomings

但正因 but just because

缺憾 there is a shortcoming

未来 the future

就有了 (precisely) will have

无限的转机 unlimited changes for the better

无限的可能性 and unlimited possibilities

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to translate,but I can explain
1)No sooner there is an imperfection then you force yourself to amend it,why?
In other words,why when a imperfection(or drawback,or something not good) come up,in that moment,that you should go the extreme lengths immediately to make up for the deficiency(or make it to be perfect).
2)Because it is not perfect,you can improve it in many ways.
(Because some reason)this satisfactory condition became a situation without satisfaction(the situation is not perfect).And the reason(the shortcoming or imperfection),it's the point.If you can amend it(the point that you can improve ),because of this you have a chance to make more possibilities.